# Opportunity field History Report

Tags: reporting, opportunity-history

Why can't I see the data under Opportunity Field History Report

[image]

I had enable History Tracking
I am the system admin
I can see data under Opportunity History report.

Am I missing any other settings, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable and set up field history tracking on opportunity object and select fields(go to fields page on that object to turn on, optionally can be shown on bottom of page layout as well) in order to use the Field History Tracking report.

Comment: Thanks Vish, I did the same after posting this question. It worked.